# Rails partial page update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have List of Users with friends/unfriends button (there are 4 states for this button according to user's relationship) I need to update button status with ajax call to server.

What is the best practice here:

1. Use `remote: true` for button and write update in users.js.erb
2. Add handler for button state and click in .js file and send requests with ajax
3. Another option I didn't mention (I'm new to Rails)

Comment: 1) use remote: true for button and write update in users.js.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I think you will find that the first option (remote: true and update via a *.js.erb template) is the best approach.

In general, this option is easy and quick to implement. As you move farther and farther down the Rails Rabbit Hole, you can play with other approaches (straight jQuery or other JS, etc.).